# Get entities if list attribute is empty

Tags: java, hibernate

I have following models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "feature")
public class DbFeature {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    public DbProduct product;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class DbProduct {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    public List<DbFeature> features;
}
```

How I can make Criteria query which will return me all products without features?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need a creteria to run SQL statement. Consult your database driver vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(DbProduct.class).createAlias("features", "feature", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN).add(Restrictions.isNull("feature"));
```

Note : It's not tested.